# Trying to make BLOB to PDF in browser using PHP

Tags: pdf, php, blob-storage

I have BLOB information from my database and trying to display a PDF file in browser using this:

```php
echo "<object data='data:application/pdf;base64,".base64_encode($row['PDF_File'])."' type='application/pdf' style='height:600px;width:60%'></object>";
```

But with the result I get a problem like this:

[image: failure]

The error message (originally in Russian) in English is:

> Error
>
> The PDF document could not be loaded.
>
> To reboot

If I change `base64_encode` to `base64_decode` it will crack, if I delete this, it won't show up.

New PDFs are added to DB by JavaScript script:

```javascript
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onload = function() {
console.log(reader.result);
  const data = {
    file_pdf: reader.result
  };
  sendForm(data);
};
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: you should probably provide a translation for any non-english language error messages. is the byte stream in your database base64 encoded? describe how new PDFs are added to the DB.

Comment: Giacomo1968, yea it's pdf.
Frank Thomas, yes, it's encoded. Error says "failed to load PDF file". New PDFs are added to DB by JS script:
```var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function() {
        console.log(reader.result);
        const data = { file_pdf: reader.result };
        sendForm(data);
    };```

Comment: so that covers the clientside upload, but not the serverside (the php or whatever of the post request).  either way I'm still not seeing anything that indicates base64 encoding, so its likely that using base64 encode/decode is not the correct transformation of byte stream. have you just tried returning the file stream contents instead of trying to encode it?

Comment: Yea i tried this, but not working either. All PDFs in my DB starts with "data:application/pdf;base64,"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20714181/117259) explains the issue.

One idea of how to get the PDF is creating a PHP file that directly downloads the PDF file like this:

```php
<?php
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
echo $row['PDF_File'];
?>
```

Or you can try to force a download by adding the `Content-Disposition` header like this; change the value of `$filename` to be whatever the filename should be:

```php
<?php
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$filename = 'the_pdf.pdf';
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
echo $row['PDF_File'];
?>
```

---

**Update 1**: Based on the original poster’s comments:

> “All PDFs in my DB starts with "data:application/pdf;base64”

If that is the case, you don’t have to use `base64_encode` again. Just change your line to the following; removing that `base64_encode`:

```php
echo "<object data='data:application/pdf;base64,".$row['PDF_File']."' type='application/pdf' style='height:600px;width:60%'></object>";
```

Or using my example with the download, change it to the following; note I am using `base64_decode` for the `echo` line to properly decode the Base64:

```php
<?php
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$filename = 'the_pdf.pdf';
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
echo base64_decode($row['PDF_File']);
?>
```

---

**Update 2**: If none of above works, my only guess is the JavaScript upload process is messed up. Or the database storage is messed up. Instead of `BLOB` for DB storage, try `LONGTEXT` for storage because you are not storing binary data but a very long Base64 encoded text string.

Comment: I see how it must work, but that doesn't help me somehow. When i open downloaded file i have the same issue(

Comment: Update: in the first case it looks normal from F12, but there is blank space 0x0 instead of pdf viewer. In the second case i get the same issue, but the pdf contain characters like "u«Zjљe‰Ж­Љ‰яҐЧЫjЗєа•AґДёР(ДЂАЃЅ‰Ё(рр(ЅLЂЅ(шш)•№‘Ѕ‰Ё(ИЂАЃЅ‰Ё(рр(Ѕ9ХµМЃlАЂДЂАЃIt(шш)•№‘Ѕ‰Ё(МЂАЃЅ‰Ё(рр(Ѕ" and so on

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot [to Giacomo1968](https://superuser.com/a/1835824/167207).

I found out that in `<object>` line with metadata duplicates the `data:application/pdf;base64,` already in the database field. So we need just remove that part.

```php
echo "<object data='data:application/pdf;base64,".$row['PDF_File']."' type='application/pdf' style='height:600px;width:60%'></object>";
```

Turns into:

```php
echo "<object type='application/pdf' data='".$row['PDF_File']."'></object>";
```